# Want to convert div into image for download purpose- Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to convert my div part of my angularjs application into image so that I can download it as per clients requirements.

```
<div class="wrap-dashboard">
<div class="dashboard">
    <div gridster="vm.gridsterOptions">
        <ul>
             <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in vm.widgets">
                <div class="box" >
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
                        <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                            <a title="Download widget" ng-click="" id="download"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i></a>
                            <a title="settings" ng-click="vm.openSettings(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a>
                            <a title="Remove widget" ng-click="vm.remove(widget)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <nvd3 options="widget.options" data="widget.options.dataList" api="widget.options.api" config="vm.config" events="vm.events"></nvd3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output of this code is a chart [image]

Now I want to download this chart, but don't know how...
Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: look at html2canvas js

Comment: yup I tried html2canvas but its supporting angularjs

Comment: no.. its just a library.. https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations

Comment: check the link above and see how to use it. you dont need to use angular with it